# Did the philosophy of Heidegger lead to any advances in scientific knowledge?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, history-of-philosophy

Heidegger seems to be one of ther most controversial figures in philosophy as some philosophers consider him the greatest philosopher of the 20th century and others a charlatan.
Analytic philosophers seem to think that his work is mostly useless and incomprehensible while some philosophers present his work as important.
Are there any scientists or engineers who benefited in their work from his philosophy or is it just mostly philosophers and non-STEMs that find his philosophy useful?

Comment: Irrespective of the valuation about the importance of Heidegger, why do you think that his thought had any impact on scientific knowledge?

Comment: There has been some exploration of using his work to illuminate cognitive science, see for example [Heidegger and Cognitive Science](https://www.amazon.com/Heidegger-Cognitive-Science-Directions-Philosophy/dp/0230216552/) (there's a review [here](https://academic.oup.com/mind/article-abstract/123/490/616/1280067?redirectedFrom=fulltext), paywalled but you can [use sci-hub to read it](https://sci-hub.st/10.1093/mind/fzu093)) and [Heidegger, Coping, and Cognitive Science](https://www.amazon.com/Heidegger-Coping-Cognitive-Science-Dreyfus/dp/0262731282/)

Comment: Some AI researchers found Heidegger's work insightful, see e.g. [Dreyfus, Why Heideggerian AI failed and how fixing it would require making it more Heideggerian](http://www.csc.kth.se/~yngve/HeideggerianAI.pdf).